# Get list of external tables created on ephemeral Dataproc clusters

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, external, google-cloud-dataproc

I created few tables on a Dataproc cluster. The cluster was later destroyed. However, I had created the table using the external command. How can I get the list of all the tables created in older clusters which no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

When an external Hive table is created, the [LOCATION parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables) is required to point to the HDFS path where data is located. Depending on what you specified in LOCATION I can say:

- If you referenced a remote cluster where the data was stored, you
  just have to go to that cluster to look for the data.
- If you specified a path inside the cluster that was removed, your
  data was also removed.

Important to notice is that every time a Dataproc cluster is shut down [its data is erased](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/resources/faq#what_happens_to_my_data_when_a_cluster_is_shut_down).